# Default FormBuilder in SimpleForm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using the [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem, and I wrote a custom form builder:

```
class MyFormBuilder < SimpleForm::FormBuilder
  def input(attribute_name, options = {}, &block)
    super if object.respond_to?(attribute_name)
  end    
end
```

I can easily use my form builder with:

```
simple_form_for(@object, builder: MyFormBuilder)
```

**However, I have many forms, how can I set a default custom form builder?** I was looking at the [Simple Form initializer template](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/generators/simple_form/templates/config/initializers/simple_form.rb) but I didn't seem to see what I'm looking for.

Note, I am using:

```
gem 'simple_form', '3.0.2'
```

Comment: Could you just overwrite the FormBuilder class? In your example, to make that the default input, just write the full, modified input method?

Comment: If I did that, I'd have to cut and paste the entire thing and make my change right? How would I go about upgrading `simple_form` when applicable?

Comment: That's a vulnerability of this solution, you're right. Check out the source code here. Doesn't look like it accepts a configuration: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/743d749d757761a71a55f59f45ab28c439f0d069/lib/simple_form/action_view_extensions/form_helper.rb